# Know size of argument in fscanf(fp , "%s" , strr1)

Tags: c++

```
char str1[10];
fscanf(fp , "%s", str1);
```

I want to know size of `%s` before assigning to `str1` to avoid crashing in case of huge input data.

Comment: You should use `fscanf_s`.

Comment: Your question is tagged `c++`. In C++, you should not be using `fscanf()` at all. Use `std::string` with `std::ifstream` and `operator>>` instead, let the `std::string` grow dynamically as needed to accommodate the full size of the string that is being read: `std::string str1; std::ifstream fp("input.txt"); fp >> str1;`

Comment: You can't know the size of the input before reading it unless you have a time machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the maximum number of characters to read:

```
fscanf(fp, "%9s", str1);
```

This will not write more than 10 chars into `str1` including the null terminator.

But in C++ you should use streams and strings which are safe in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is C++, you don't have to rely on `fscanf`. We can avoid buffer overflow altogether by using `std::istream`:

```
std::string readWord(std::istream& input) {
    std::string word;
    if(input >> word) {
        return word; 
    } else { 
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

This will automatically read characters until reaching the first whitespace character is encountered, and it'll automatically allocate memory as needed.